Где можно найти нормальные документации по Media Foundation?
Мне необходимо изучить эту библиотеку, но при попытках найти по ней документацию, мне выдают только сайт майкрософт. Как мне кажется, они даже не делают вид что хотят сделать документацию понятной. Подчеркиваю. МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ. Плюс к тому, значительная часть самых важных объяснений происходит в коментариях кода. А их браузер не переводит. Может кто нибудь посоветовать сайты на которых есть наиболее понятные документации к этой библиотеке (вот что бы прям до идиота дошло)?
